# istio failing with "failed checking application ports"

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Using `istio 1.0.2` and `kubernetes 1.12` on GKE.

When deploying a web application, the pod never reaches the healthy status.

My main pod spits out healthy logs.

However, my sidecar, i.e. the `istio-proxy` container reads:

```
* failed checking application ports. listeners="0.0.0.0:15090","10.8.48.10:53","10.8.63.194:15443","10.8.63.194:443","10.8.58.47:15011","10.8.54.249:42422","10.8.48.44:443","10.8.58.10:44134","10.8.54.34:443","10.8.63.194:15020","10.8.49.250:8080","10.8.63.194:31400","10.8.63.194:15029","10.8.63.194:15030","10.8.60.185:11211","10.8.49.0:53","10.8.61.194:443","10.8.48.1:443","10.8.48.180:80","10.8.51.133:443","10.8.63.194:15031","10.8.63.194:15032","0.0.0.0:9901","0.0.0.0:9090","0.0.0.0:80","0.0.0.0:3000","0.0.0.0:8060","0.0.0.0:15010","0.0.0.0:8080","0.0.0.0:20001","0.0.0.0:7979","0.0.0.0:9091","0.0.0.0:9411","0.0.0.0:15004","0.0.0.0:15014","0.0.0.0:3030","10.8.33.8:15020","0.0.0.0:15001"
* envoy missing listener for inbound application port: 5000
```

`5000` is **indeed** the port my web app is listening on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running the managed version GKE offers? If not, how are you injecting the sidecar? By default, the sidecar gets injected using mutating webhooks, so there should be no need to use annotations to open the ports.

Comment: Have you solved this problem @pkaramol? Becaus both answers didn't solve this for me.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a mismatch between deployment port and service port this can cause some issues in combination with the readiness of the sidecar.

Add the annotation readiness.status.sidecar.istio.io/applicationPorts in your deployment like this:

```
annotations:
    readiness.status.sidecar.istio.io/applicationPorts: "5000"
```

You can add multiple ports by using comma separation.

Answer (score 0):

@mkrobi I got this working as suggested in [this post](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/9504#issuecomment-512343407) by adding the following-

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: 8080
    scheme: HTTP
```

to the `containers` in my `deployment`. Make sure to change port `8080` to `5000`.